# Any function to read/get logs in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am looking for a simple built in function or solution where I can get latest 10 logs or past hours logs and read how many are there and what kind of errors they are.

( I tried google but didn't find any )
I also tried looking on this page https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors but I don't seems to find any. Are there ?

I wanted to create an hourly cronjob to check for logs and see how many logs were there in the past hour and what kind of logs each were so I could send push notification or email to my phone.

**I am NOT looking for external platform/service for log viewer**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For logging you can use this library

It is very useful for reading logs.

[Laravel Log Viewer](https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer)

[Monoglog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog)

This will be helpful library. It will read all the `log` from `.log` file

[log-reader](https://github.com/stevebauman/log-reader)

Comment: I am using this library but thats basically user interface for viewing logs on backend.  They don't seems to have function to get logs and do anotherthing of ur own. Please read my question carefully :) . Thanks for suggestion btw.

Comment: I had given another link in my answer just check Monolog library

Comment: Nope its not what I want.